# How can I d3.js Different char input data in flask mysql?

Tags: javascript, mysql, d3.js, flask

I have a Question.

I will use to d3.js using Different chart.

How can I input data using mysql?

Generally, many examples using csv or tsv data.
I know that using this.
But.. I wanna using mysql not csv or tsv dataset.

How can I do this?

data is here

```
  Date        Temperature      Humidity
2010-01-01        50              40
2010-01-02        55              35
   ...            ...             ...
```

I using web development using flask.
data is getting json.

example)

```
   var data = JSON.parser({{ data | tojson}});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

2 Options:

1. Make an XHR requests (e.g. you can use `d3.json(url, function(data) {...});`) from the browser and on the server side query MySQL and then use Flask's `return jsonify(data)`.
2. Write out a JSON object from jinja2 directly into a template like the example you show but: `var data = {{ data|tojson|safe }};`. Note that this has to be in a template file being rendered by Flask's `render_template` function.